# ChannelRedirect() hangs the associated channel in a call?

Tags: asterisk

i am writing a dialplan for conference calling using Asterisk13.8 and want to move the channels to conference room during call when either caller or callee press specific key. i am using ChannelRedirect() application but it only transfers one channel to conference, other get hanged. how to move both channels to conference room???

Answer (score 0):

ChannelRedirect send other extension to same context priority +100, like described in doc. You just have ensure you have that priority in diallplan.

Comment: i tried it by adding context,priority+100,GoTo(conf), still 2nd extension does not enter conference room?

Comment: using ami redirect i successfully redirect both channels to conference room but wondering why ChannelRedirect() is not working?